# Rotate svg onclick

Tags: javascript, html, svg, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to rotate the pink area onclick and move to a new angle from the current position.

We need to save the current position and on click we need to move from current position to new position.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you remove the example code you posted? If you got your answer, leave it for others who may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is that you are using a div inside the svg element. You can try to use a `<g>` element instead.
Also many css rules for `.circle_seg` are useless. I've commented those out but I've added [pointer-events:all;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events). This will make the "segments" sensitive to mouse events like click.

```
.circle_seg {
  /*height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;*/
  pointer-events:all;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works on all the browsers except IE. On ie , when I click anywhere on the pink region, it just jumps to the new segment without gradually moving. Could you suggest any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: `pointer-events` should work on IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events. The fact that "it jumps" means that the "segments" are sensitive to the mouse. It may be something else that it doesn't work. It would be nice to see your code

Comment: Here is the link - https://codepen.io/linamary/pen/zgWvoN   , and the debug mode link for IE is - https://s.codepen.io/linamary/debug/zgWvoN/vWkRwRbPBWOM